# Port currently owned by Unknown Windows Application - Barcode Reading Issue

Tags: serial-port, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have written the program to reader barcode using Device Argox barcode reader , Model no As-8250 in java.
I am using javax.com jar for serial commuication.
Here is program which i have written to read from port number COM13 .

I have also set default port number of my Argox Utility to COM13.

```
package scanhandler;


import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;

import javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier;
import javax.comm.PortInUseException;
import javax.comm.SerialPort;
import javax.comm.SerialPortEvent;
import javax.comm.SerialPortEventListener;
import javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException;

public class ScanHandler implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {

    private static CommPortIdentifier   myCommPortIdentifier;
    private static Enumeration          portList;
    private static String               TimeStamp;
    private static String               driverClass;
    private static String               connectionString;
    private static String               comPort;    

    private Connection                  myConnection;
    private InputStream                 myInputStream;
    private Robot                       myRobot;
    private SerialPort                  mySerialPort;
    private Thread                      myThread;


    public ScanHandler() {

        // open serial port
        try {
            TimeStamp = new java.util.Date().toString();
            mySerialPort = (SerialPort) myCommPortIdentifier.open("ComControl", 2000);
            //System.out.println(TimeStamp + ": " + myCommPortIdentifier.getName() + " opened for scanner input");
        } catch (PortInUseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // get serial input stream
        try {
            myInputStream = mySerialPort.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // add an event listener on the port
        try {
            mySerialPort.addEventListener(this);
        } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mySerialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

        // set up the serial port properties
        try {
            mySerialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            mySerialPort.setDTR(false);
            mySerialPort.setRTS(false);

        } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // make a robot to pass keyboard data
        try {
            myRobot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // create the thread
        myThread = new Thread(this);
        myThread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    // on scan
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {

        if (event.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {

            StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            int c;
            try {

                // append the scanned data onto a string builder
                while ((c = myInputStream.read()) != 10){
                   if (c != 13)  myStringBuilder.append((char) c);
                }               

                // send to keyboard buffer if it the barcode doesn't start with '5'
                if (myStringBuilder.charAt(0) != '5') {

                    for (int i = 0; i < myStringBuilder.length(); i++) {
                        myRobot.keyPress((int) myStringBuilder.charAt(i));
                        myRobot.keyRelease((int) myStringBuilder.charAt(i));
                    }

                // here's the scanned barcode as a variable!
                } else {
                    TimeStamp = new java.util.Date().toString();
                    System.out.println(TimeStamp + ": scanned input received:" + myStringBuilder.toString());                    
                }

                // close the input stream
                myInputStream.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // read ScanHandler properties
        Properties myProperties = new Properties();
        // myProperties.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
        comPort             = "COM13";              

        try {

            // get our pre-defined COM port
            myCommPortIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(comPort);
            ScanHandler reader = new ScanHandler();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            TimeStamp = new java.util.Date().toString();
            System.out.println(TimeStamp + ": " + comPort + " " + myCommPortIdentifier);
            System.out.println(TimeStamp + ": msg1 - " + e);
        }
    };    
}
```

-> this program is listening  on port COM13 .and print the string whatever in the input stream (Scanned by Barcode Reader).

->==========================Problem is Here=======================
when i pluged in Usb first and force it by Device utility to use port COM13 . it work pefectly.
After that when i run my Java program to listen on same port it throws Exception

```
javax.comm.PortInUseException: Port currently owned by Unknown Windows Application
    at javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.open(CommPortIdentifier.java:337)
    at scanhandler.ScanHandler.<init>(ScanHandler.java:41)
    at scanhandler.ScanHandler.main(ScanHandler.java:141)
Fri Jun 13 12:20:05 IST 2014: COM13 javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier@d1a2f1
Fri Jun 13 12:20:05 IST 2014: msg1 - java.lang.NullPointerException
```

So how could i read scanned barcode , if my proram is getting refused  to listen on that port.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: You need to find out which process has that serial port opened already and end it so that your program can open that port.

Answer (score 0):

The following will show you the PID of the application currently using a specific port:

```
C:\Users\user>netstat -ano | findstr ":5984"
```

Output will look something like:

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5984         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2036
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5984         127.0.0.1:55706        ESTABLISHED     2036
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5984         127.0.0.1:55710        ESTABLISHED     2036
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5984         127.0.0.1:55711        ESTABLISHED     2036
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5984         127.0.0.1:55712        ESTABLISHED     2036
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5984         127.0.0.1:55713        ESTABLISHED     2036
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5984         127.0.0.1:55714        ESTABLISHED     2036
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55706        127.0.0.1:5984         ESTABLISHED     4716
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55710        127.0.0.1:5984         ESTABLISHED     4716
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55711        127.0.0.1:5984         ESTABLISHED     4716
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55712        127.0.0.1:5984         ESTABLISHED     4716
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55713        127.0.0.1:5984         ESTABLISHED     4716
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55714        127.0.0.1:5984         ESTABLISHED     4716
```

You can then use the `tasklist` command or Task Manager to find the name:

```
C:\Users\user>tasklist | findstr "2036"
erl.exe                       2036 Services                   0     15,604 K
```

Comment: Jullian thanks for your answer , by your answer i can get the Application name using purticular port.but the question is if my Bacode reader device is using whatever port , but if i have to read scanned result so how can i read it without litsening on same port. and if do that(means same port for reading input stream ) then it throws error-> port already in use.

Comment: Have you opened the port correctly in Java? I'm not a Java programmer I'm afraid but often when you are opening ports and files, you can set a mode. Some modes are exclusive and will not share.

Comment: yes as shown in my code i have open the port correctly , but as you said some ports are shared then if i make COM13 shared then it might work , but i does not know how to make port shared. do you have an idea about that?

Comment: I'm afraid that's as far as my knowledge of Java goes. If I get time, I'll try and do some digging.